# Chained inscribed circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Of the nth circle, in terms of r, the radius of the large green circle? Notice that the two red circles are equal, both with radius $\frac{r}{2}$

How to solve this without using René Descartes's theorem?

Problem found at page 17 of ''[Problema Bonitos de Geometría con métodos elementales](http://www.cfrd.cl/~moises/DVD/05Bibliografia%20-%20Geometria%20Sagrada/Matematica%20Recreativa/MISCELANEA/Problemas%20bonitos%20de%20geometr%C3%ADa.pdf)'' (a large pdf). Solution by René Descartes's theorem at page 44.

Can you solve the problem by Pappus Chain?

Comment: At what stage are you? Did you find the radii of the yellow circles, e.g.?

Comment: I put the title of the pdf above where I got this question. The complete resolution, by Descartes' theorem, is there. I wonder if there is another method of solving without using that theorem.

Comment: To be clear: You want the radius of the $n$-th **blue** circle. (Does the largest count as $n=0$, or as $n=1$?) ... Also, you've been here long enough that this question shouldn't have to be asked, but: *What have you tried?* (You should put the link to the reference in the body of your question; comments are easily overlooked. Please also provide a translation of the solution from the PDF, as you did with the question. Note that people may be rightfully hesitant about clicking links to random files on the web.)

Comment: Got it. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Pappus Chain. It is for n = 1

Comment: [Pappus-Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_chain) problem is a sub-problem of this question.  it is about determining  the radii of the orange circles. Once you get that, you get compute the radii of blue circles using Descartes theorem. To directly determine the radii of the blue circles, consider a circle inversion with respect to the endpoint of the semicircle on the left. It will map the orange circles to circles sandwiched between two vertical lines. The blue circles will be placed in the space between two orange circles and a vertical line.